# Ruby cannot JSON.parse(file.to_json)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hash in a text file, but I'm getting a JSONParseError 757 when I run the below command.

```
file = File.open("output.txt", "r")
test = JSON.parse(file.to_json)
```

However, my test works when I manually type in the hash i.e.

```
test = JSON.parse(({test=>test}).to_json)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: (Logs generated is here)

```
[2] pry(main)> data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
JSON::ParserError: 399: unexpected token at '{"id"=>"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:738647950117593089", "objectType"=>"activity", "verb"=>"post", "postedTime"=>"2016-06-03T08:26:09.000Z", "generator"=>{"displayName"=>"Facebook", "link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/twitter"}, "provider"=>{"objectType"=>"service", "displayName"=>"Twitter", "link"=>"http://www.twitter.com"}, "link"=>"http://twitter.com/AliyuAchimugu/statuses/738647950117593089", "body"=>"Kwara Govt. urges farmers to embrace modern farming to boost food security.\n\nSee details... ", "actor"=>{"objectType"=>"person", "id"=>"id:twitter.com:1317525900", "link"=>"http://www.twitter.com/AliyuAchimugu", "displayName"=>"Achimugu Aliyu", "postedTime"=>"2013-03-31T02:04:27.000Z", "image"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png", "summary"=>"Humanitarian | Entrepreneur |Great Survivor | Social Entrepreneur | Passionately Curious | Always Willing to Learn", "friendsCount"=>16, "followersCount"=>214, "listedCount"=>43, "statusesCount"=>161004, "twitterTimeZone"=>nil, "verified"=>false, "utcOffset"=>nil, "preferredUsername"=>"AliyuAchimugu", "languages"=>["en"], "links"=>[{"href"=>"https://facebook.com/AchimuguNoni", "rel"=>"me"}], "location"=>{"objectType"=>"place", "displayName"=>"Abuja,Nigeria"}, "favoritesCount"=>0}, "object"=>{"objectType"=>"note", "id"=>"object:search.twitter.com,2005:738647950117593089", "summary"=>"Kwara Govt. urges farmers to embrace modern farming to boost food security.\n\nSee details... ", "link"=>"http://twitter.com/AliyuAchimugu/statuses/738647950117593089", "postedTime"=>"2016-06-03T08:26:09.000Z"}, "favoritesCount"=>0, "twitter_entities"=>{"hashtags"=>[], "urls"=>[{"url"=>"test", "expanded_url"=>"test", "display_url"=>"test", "indices"=>[92, 115]}], "user_mentions"=>[], "symbols"=>[]}, "twitter_lang"=>"en", "retweetCount"=>0, "gnip"=>{"matching_rules"=>[{"value"=>"lang:en (argiculture OR farming) (ad leader OR data OR driverless OR gps OR internet of things OR iot OR john deere OR mobile OR monsanto OR security OR sensors OR tech OR technology OR toro) ", "tag"=>nil}], "urls"=>[{"url"=>"test", "expanded_url"=>"https://www.facebook.com/naijacomedyjokes/posts/1124075157654916", "expanded_status"=>nil, "expanded_url_title"=>nil, "expanded_url_description"=>nil}]}, "twitter_filter_level"=>"low"}]
'
from /home/blau08/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

Comment: What does `file.to_json` return (it's a hint)?

Comment: I have added one approach we used, hope it will help. please write queries in comments

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following steps:

```
#1 Require JSON
gem install json

#2 Open JSON file for Parsing
file = File.read('file-name-to-be-read.json')

#3 Parse Data from File
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
```

Hint:

```
file = File.read("output.txt")
test = JSON.parse(file)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I keep getting this error. I have no idea why it when I read a file, it always adds or deletes an extra character. I edited it up.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to write it as JSON. Can't write Ruby objects to file.